# Vuex | How to commit a global mutation in a module action?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have an action in a namespaced module and a global mutation (i.e. not in a module). I would like to be able to commit the global mutation inside the action.

```
// Global mutation
export default {
  globalMutation (state, payload) {
    ...
  }
}

// Action in a namespaced module
export default {
  namespaced: true,

  actions: {
    namespacedAction ({ commit, dispatch, state }, payload) {
      commit({ type: 'globalMutation' })
    }
  }
}
```

When the namespaced action is dispatched, Vuex displays:

```
[vuex] unknown local mutation type: globalMutation, global type: module/globalMutation
```

Is there an option I can pass to the `commit` function to call this global mutation?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Looks like I just found a way with the `{ root: true }` parameter.

```
commit('globalMutation', payload, { root: true })
```

---

If module is namespaced, use global path instead:

```
commit('module/mutation', payload, { root: true })
```

Comment: just want to add something  : if global has " namespaced: true," you  have to do :

commit('global/globalMutation', payload, { root: true })

Comment: More info here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#commit
( { root: true} works also for dispatch btw. )